# What the difference beetween "#" and "." in css?

Tags: css

I don't know the difference between "#" and "."to make a class. Example:

```
  .teste {
  color: red;
  }

  #teste {
   color: red;
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

`#` refers to the Id of an element, while `.` refers to a class. Read through https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors

Answer (score 1):

`#` refer to IDs of HTML elements. `.` refer to classes of HTML elements.

Given your example, the `.teste` will color the first `div` red, and the `#teste` will color the second `div` red.

```
<div class="teste"></div>
<div id="teste"></div>
```

See http://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/css_selectors.asp for more info.

Answer (score 1):

'#' signifies a css 'id' whereas '.' is a css 'class'. Functionally they are the same, but conventionally you should only use an id once per page, and a class for multiple elements on the same page.